# Wordpress: Different look for different posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've looked everywhere to work out how to do this, but I'm having no luck. I read up on Post Formats, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

All the posts on the frontpage are the same, but say, for features or reviews you can have an entirely different look compared to the "standard" single.php post.

Examples:

**Homepage //**
http:// ausdroid.net (All posts look the same)

**Standard single post //**
http://ausdroid.net/2013/02/03/samsung-galaxy-nexus-from-vodafone-receives-android-4-1-2-update

**Different single post (for a review in this case) //**
http://ausdroid.net/2013/02/02/huawei-ascend-d1-quad-review

Thanks!

Comment: if i remember correctly this involves custom post types

Comment: What have you tried / How's your knowledge on WordPress? If you have no experience, I suggest to [look here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) first.

Comment: @IanO.S not necessarily. Custom Post Type is quite new and involves/affects more than what (I think) the OP wants to achieve. We can have different layouts by detecting categories, tags, or even single post.

Comment: @IanO.S. I saw that before, but 1) I don't think that's what I'm looking for, looks like it's for seperate content to "posts", could be mistaken!

Comment: [A graphical presentation of WP template](http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png)

Comment: @rlatief Hey, I do have enough knowledge to build a basic Wordpress theme from scratch, but that's really it. So I can build a nice website with your standard posts and different page templates, but never worked with different post templates.

Comment: You can try adding custom fields to the posts and check them in the single.php to show different layouts. See this video for and example of a plugin doing just that - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3VXnryN9iY

Comment: @morart What separates the Posts (that should have different templates)? Categories/tags?

Comment: @rlatief Nothing specific. I was hoping that I could just pick a different template for whichever I post I want. Like with a dropdown menu during the new post page.

Comment: Ah! In that case you're probably looking for [Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). It has limitations, but the other option would involve creating plugins that modifies the Post page.

Comment: @rlatief I read up on that before, but I was just confused by it. I'll give it another look!

Comment: `I could just pick a different template for whichever I post` is why you must use Post Formats. It'll automatically put the ability to select which Format to use, to the Post editor. Other option would require you to write a more complex code. Unless if we're talking about Page which'll automatically show Page template selection (if available) in the Page editor.

Comment: Ok, I believe I figured it out. I'm using this plugin called [Custom Post Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/). I just need to create a php like single-example.php and add at the very top:

    `<?php
    /*
    Template Name Posts: Example
    */
    ?>`

So like custom page templates, but I needed the plugin to show the dropdown box on the new post page, otherwise it wouldn't show up! Thought I should post this in case anyone else wanted to know how to do the same.

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/

this explains it pretty well using " Single Post Template" plugin, if thats an option

Comment: This is a very old plugin... (Compatible up to: 2.9.2)

Comment: @m1r0 It looked promising! Is there another plugin that's updated, or can it be done without the need for a plugin in recent Wordpress versions?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/   - this version supports through wordpress 3.4 or higher

Comment: @IanO.S. Just saw this plugin recommendation now after I posted about it. Works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sample on using category to present different Singles:

`single.php`

```
<?php

if ( in_category( $foo ) )
    require( 'single-foo.php' );
else
    require( 'single-default.php' );
```

So you'll have the above simple code in the usual `single.php`, put your previous `single.php` to `single-default.php`, and create your "other" Single layout in `single-foo.php`.

$foo can be category ID or Slug.

[in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

**EDIT**

You can modify this to work with Post Formats:

In functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
```

... then, change the `if` statement in my sample above to use `has_post_format()` instead.

[has_post_format()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_format).

Comment: The problem with this is that then an entire category will have a different template, not posts which I can pick and choose to have a different look. Like with a dropdown menu in the new post page.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding custom fields to the posts and check them in the single.php to show different layouts. See this video for and example of a plugin doing just that - youtube.com/watch?v=L3VXnryN9iY

Comment: I already use custom fields on my sites, and I don't see how this would work with what I want.

Comment: You just add a select custom field named Layouts, lets say with values - Layout 1, Layout 2, etc... In the single you check if the Layouts field value is Layout 1 then show this html, if it is Layout 2 then show this html. And thats it.